# Code error in iOS Xcode app

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my Viewcontroller.m I have this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {

    NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];

    //Get path directory
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //Create PDF_Documents directory
    documentsDirectory = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"PDF_Documents"];
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];

    NSString *filePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@", documentsDirectory, @"My PDF File"];

    [dataPdf writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];

    [self refresh:self];

    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self.imageView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Picture.tiff"]];

    [self.scrollView setMaximumZoomScale:10.0f];
    [self.scrollView setClipsToBounds:YES];

    _myBotton.layer.borderWidth =2.0f;
    _myBotton.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor redColor]CGColor];
}
```

At: `NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url];` I get this error: `Use of undeclared identifier 'pdfOnline'`

At: `[[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];` I get this error: Expected `':'`

How can I solve these errors? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

This is what errors means:

You are using pdfOnline but this variables is not defined on the current scope. pdfOnline seems like a property in the class. try using "self.pdfOnline" and also double check the header files contains that property.

> t: NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:pdfOnline.url]; I
>   get this error: Use of undeclared identifier 'pdfOnline'

You are misspelling this(not sure what you want here)

> At: [[NSFileManager defaultManager] documentsDirectory
>   withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil]; I get this
>   error: Expected ':'

Try:

```
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] createDirectoryAtPath:documentsDirectory withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:nil];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.


Still one error:
NSData *dataPdf = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:self.pdfOnline];

Property 'pdfOnline' not found on object of type 'ViewController *'

Comment: seems like you didn't define this pdfOnline as a local variable neither as property on the controller self.pdfOnline